# HTACCESS Profile Redirection Regex Not Substituting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

My goal is to rewrite URLs requesting a specific profile from the form `profile/name` to a PHP script that will take `name` into itself and spit out this person's profile. To accomplish this I use the following statement:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+) profile/view.php?username=$1 [NC]
```

The problem is that no matter what I use for `name`, it always redirects me to `profile/view.php?username=view.php`. I have absolutely no idea why and have tried everything to no avail. What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rewrite engine loops through all the rules until the URI stops changing. Because of that, the `view.php` is matching the `([^/]+)` regex the next time the rules loop.

Try adding some conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+) profile/view.php?username=$1 [L,NC]
```

---

EDIT: bit of an explanation

The rewrite engine loops, so consider the request URI as a variable of sorts. And this variable is what the regex of a rewrite rule matches against.

So if your rule is simply:

```
RewriteRule ^profile/([^/]+) profile/view.php?username=$1 [NC]
```

This is what the rewrite engine is going to do:

1. URI = `/profile/myname`
2. Does `^profile/([^/]+)` match the URI? Yes
3. The grouping matches "myname" and is backreferenced by the rule's target.
4. URI = `/profile/view.php?username=myname`
5. Rewrite engine loops
6. Does the regex match `/profile/view.php`? (Note, the query string is not part of what gets matched in a rewrite rule) Yes
7. The grouping matches "view.php" and is backreference by the rule's target.
8. URI = `/profile/view.php?username=view.php`
9. Rewrite engine loops
10. same thing happens except the URI is no longer changed, so the rewrite engine stops

final URI: `/profile/view.php?username=view.php`

Comment: Thank you very much! That did the trick. Still don't entirely understand though.

Comment: @Confiqure I added a bit of an explanation